# Recursive function in Python giving unexpected output

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a recursive function which purpose is to find the smallest positive integer that is not present within a list of numbers.

The function works fine when the numbers are arranged in an order, but if they are not in order then this gives unexpected results. For example, input [1, 2, 3] will return 4 which is good, but [1, 3, 2] will return 3, which is unexpected.

```
A = [1, 2, 3]
def solution(A):
    smallestpositiveinteger = recursivesearch(A)
    return smallestpositiveinteger

def recursivesearch(A, integer = 1):
    for number in A:
        if (number == integer) :
            integer += 1
            recursivesearch(A, integer)
    return integer
varSolution = solution(A)
print(varSolution)
```

Comment: What was the point of calling the function recursively, if you're just going to ignore its return value?

Comment: This isn't a good fit for recursion in Python. Given a long enough list, you'll overflow the stack. Use a regular while loop.

Comment: Even worse, if A has a "hole", it will fail also spectaculary: A = [1, 2, 4] yields 3 as well.

Comment: to Laerne - the purpose of this function is to find the smallest integer that is not present within the set of numbers. Therefore, yielding 3 with input of [1, 2, 4] is exactly what I am looking for.
im not sure what jasonharper means when he says that i am ignoring the return value

Comment: He means The line `recursivesearch(A, integer)` should be `return recursivesearch(A, integer)`

Comment: JasonHarper's answer is the correct answer, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
def solution(A, i=1):
    A = set(A) # remove duplicates
    if i in A:
        return solution(A, i+1)
    else:
        return i
```

This function first removes duplicates and then calls itself recursively with the next integer i+1 if the current integer i is in the set A. If it's not, it returns i as the missing positive integer.